# What is the optimal architecture design on Azure for an infrequently used backend that needs a robust configuration?

Tags: azure, hpc, azure-batch

I'm trying to find the optimal cloud architecture to host a software on Microsoft Azure.

The scenario is the following:

- A (containerised) REST API is exposed to the users through which they can submit POST and GET requests. POST requests trigger a backend that needs a robust configuration to operate properly and GET requests are sent to fetch the result of the backend, if any. This component of the solution is currently hosted on an Azure Web App Service which does the job perfectly.
- The (containerised) backend (triggered by POST requests) perform heavy calculations during a short amount of time (typically 5-10 minutes are allotted for the calculation). This backend needs (at least) 4 cores and 16 Gb RAM, but the more the better.

The current configuration consists in the backend hosted together with the REST API on the App Service with a plan that accommodates the backend's requirements. This is clearly not very cost-efficient, as the backend is idle ~90% of the time. On top of that it's not really scalable despite an automatic scaling rule to spawn new instances based on the CPU use: it's indeed possible that if several POST requests come at the same time, they are handled by the same instance and make it crash due to a lack of memory.

- Azure Functions doesn't seem to be an option: the serverless (consumption plan) solution they propose is restricted to 1.5 Gb RAM and doesn't have Docker support.
- Azure Container Instances neither, because first the max number of CPUs is 4 (which is really few for the needs here, although acceptable) and second there are cold starts of approximately 2 minutes (I imagine due to the creation of the container group, pull of the image, and so on). Despite the process is async from a user perspective, a high latency is not allowed as the result is expected within 5-10 minutes, so cold starts are a problem.
- Azure Batch, which at first glance appears to be a perfect fit (beefy configurations available, made for hpc, cost effective, made for time limited tasks, ...) seems to be slow too (it takes a couple of minutes to create a pool and jobs don't run immediately when submitted).

Do you have any idea what I could use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

### Azure Functions

You could look at **Azure Functions Elastic Premium** plan. EP3 has 4 cores,    14GB of RAM and 250GB of storage.

Premium plan hosting provides the following benefits to your functions:

- Avoid cold starts with perpetually warm instances
- Virtual network connectivity.
- Unlimited execution duration, with 60 minutes guaranteed.
- Premium instance sizes: one core, two core, and four core instances.
- More predictable pricing, compared with the Consumption plan.
- High-density app allocation for plans with multiple function apps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?tabs=portal

### Batch Considerations

When designing an application that uses **Batch**, you must consider the possibility of Batch not being available in a region. It's possible to encounter a rare situation where there is a problem with the region as a whole, the entire Batch service in the region, or your specific Batch account.

If the application or solution using Batch always needs to be available, then it should be designed to either failover to another region or always have the workload split between two or more regions. Both approaches require at least two Batch accounts, with each account located in a different region.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/high-availability-disaster-recovery

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The drawback with the az Functions EP3 plan (which I previously considered) is that one instance must be allocated all the time, hence making that choice not cost-effective and quite similar to the App Service. Maybe I should reformulate: is it possible to have a solution that scales to 0 instance (so really no cost) when there's no backend work to process and that can scale up almost instantaneously (let's say within 1 or 2 minutes) to n instances of a beefy config (let's say 8 CPUs/16Gb RAM)? Could AKS help me in that? I know I'm perhaps greedy, but who knows. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, that's the tough part of your question.  You have to pay to have those instances on stand-by.  I think this is the case with AKS as well but would love to hear from others with more AKS experience.

Comment: When you said 0 instance cost effectiveness Azure container apps came to mind. Have you resolved this already @RenaudChrétien ?

Comment: For the moment I'm using Batch with a time-based autoscale formula calibrated on the expected number of concurrent workers (to save cost out of business hours). Low-priority VMs are provisioned to accommodate a sudden spike in the workload. It's not perfect, but the queuing mechanism Batch provides is quite convenient so that Batch is a good trade-off. Thanks for indicating me to use container apps, I'll have a look!